# Logstash - prevent to loading logdata

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash

I have log data from tomcat server(logback), and would like to analysis it.
So, this is my thought.

logback log data -> logstash -> elasticsearch -> request elastic query.

[image]

From some other architecture, there is redis in front of logback, becuase logback has no buffer.

If I would like to do this in real time, is redis requeried?

Or no need it because all data is already stored in elastic? than why are they using redis for it?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171550/what-is-the-point-of-redis-in-elk-stack/37222286#37222286