# Log monitoring setup options in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-stack, amazon-cloudwatch

We are planning on setting up log monitoring on aws we are brainstorming on different possibilities. I would like to clarify the below points:

1) monitoring using ELK setup on aws.

2)Cloudwatch logs>lambda > elastic search> kibana.

I would like to know if the second approach is a good one as we have our logs already in cloudwatch.
What could be the difference in both the approaches and which approach is better.

Your advice would be of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that setting up your own ELK stack (option 1) usually also involves something in front of it as buffer, like Redis or Kafka. Personally I think that's a lot of moving parts, but your milage may differ.

Alternatively to option 1 & 2, you can also use Kinesis with [this connector](https://github.com/awslabs/cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer). Full disclaimer: I have no experience with this setup, but it seems very viable and easy to experiment with.

Comment: Hi @Bram, Thank you , could you please tell me more about the buffer which would be required in fornt of elk?

Comment: There's a [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171550/what-is-the-point-of-redis-in-elk-stack) about the usage of a buffer for your ELK stack.